# How can I re-instantiate a dependency for a class on each function call from within that class?

Tags: php, oop

I have a `Helpers` class, a collection of helpful, no-side-effect functions, this object also depends on a `Scraper`. The problem with this is that, if I pass this object through the constructor:

```
public function __constructor( $scraper )
{
    this->scraper = $scraper;
}
...
new Helpers( new Scraper);
```

Each function that uses `(Obj:Scraper) $this->scraper` in a manner like `$this->scraper->functionCallHere` will **make calls to the scraper object that has MAYBE had its state set (internal variables) by other function calls in the past.**

Let's look at what happens if `Helpers` has two functions which both depend on the `Scraper`:

```
public function getImages()
{
    //maybe some logic.
    return $this->scraper->getImages();
}
```

And assume we just called `getImages`, now our `$scraper` object has had its internal state changed. Assume we then call the next function `getComments`:

```
public function getComments()
{
    //maybe some logic.
    return $this->scraper->getComments();
}
```

...it will use the old `$scraper` and its state. In my case, this is very, very bad, because I'm using an external package which saves quite a bit of data in its internal state about HTTP requests, user sessions, etc., so cases where I am trying to `getComments` but with parameters that `getImages` set are certain to happen.

How can I make each function call use a new instance of that scraper object without hardcoding the instantiation of the object in each function, such that dependencies are not clear? I don't wanna end up littering my code with these. In short, how can I cleanly create "function dependencies"?

*I'll be honest. Me having this issue smells like the classic "if you have this issue, you're certainly trying to do the wrong thing".*

Comment: Seems that you need to use static classes. Is that what you want? Like `Scrapper::getComments()`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte My god, you smelled it from a mile away. It was actually my initial intention, given the nature of the `Helpers` class is that of "somewhat related, helpful functions". Regardless, I don't see how the functions being static or not solves my issue, tho. I still pass the `Scrapper` to `Helpers` and it still uses the same object. I am just basically trying to, on each function call from `Helpers`, re-instantiate the `Scrapper` object.

Comment: Sounds bad design to me. Helpers "usually" are static, as it doesn't need to have states. If the `Helpers` need a different instance of `Scrapper` every function call, you may need to actually create a new instance every time. You may want to create some `ScrapperHelper` that create a new instance of scrapper every call. Hard to tell without seeing entire project.

Answer (score -1):

I notice you're doing `$this->scraper->whatever()` so why not instead just do `$this->getScraper()->whatever()` where the `getScraper()` function returns a new instance of the scraper object?

You could make your helper functions static then like someone else suggested:

```
<?php

class Helpers {
   public static function getScraper () {
      return new Scraper();
   }

   public static function getImages () {
      $scraper = static::getScraper();
      // logic
      return $scraper->getImages();
   }
}
```

Or, depending on what it is you're doing exactly you might need to clone the scraper whenever a method in your helpers class needs to use it:

```
<?php

class Helpers {
   private $scraper;
   public function __construct ($scraper) {
      $this->scraper = $scraper;
   }
   public function getScraper () {
      return clone $this->scraper;
   }
   public function getImages () {
      $scraper = $this->getScraper();
      // logic - not sure if this modifies $scraper
      return $scraper->getImages();
   }
}
```

Last solution feels a bit hacky

Comment: That could work, yes, but, given its hard-coding, this violates everything about SOLID. The real application of what you're saying is: https://repl.it/repls/WickedSentimentalNormalform / This ensures that the scrapper object can be DI'd properly.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it is to clone the scrapper object whenever you need it then.  Nothing else is coming to mind but might think of something later.

Comment: Yes, which is what I did, but over an interface, such that the system can recognize that `Scrapper` is indeed also a `Transient` object. Your approach is mine, but with the issues relating to SOLID. If you go over my link and think it's better than this approach and you edit your answer, I can approve it (since you thought about it, you're right and I don't need the reputation).

Comment: Yeah, I mean in the link you sent you're still instantiating a new copy of the scrapper object every time you need a copy of it, which looks great to me.  This isn't exactly the same as cloning it but I thought that felt a bit hacky anyway.  See the second bit in my answer that I added earlier.